# Trouble with xinput_calibrator on a Toughbook CF-19

Tags: xorg, touchscreen, xinput

Using Xubuntu 19.10, I'm attempting to calibrate the touchscreen of a Toughbook CF-19 MK5. I've used `xinput_calibrator` as [others have suggested](https://askubuntu.com/q/251214/129686) which completes and gives me a snippet to copy into an xorg.conf file, but there's a problem:

```
chris@helmhorn:~$ sudo xinput_calibrator -v
Calibrating standard Xorg driver "Fujitsu Component USB Touch Panel Pen (0)"
        current calibration values: min_x=0, max_x=16777215 and min_y=0, max_y=16777215
        If these values are estimated wrong, either supply it manually with the --precalib option, or run the 'get_precalib.sh' script to automatically get it (through HAL).
DEBUG: Name 'Fujitsu Component USB Touch Panel Pen (0)' does not match any in '/sys/class/input/event*/device/name'
        --> Making the calibration permanent <--
  copy the snippet below into '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf' (/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ in some distro's)
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "calibration"
        MatchProduct    "!!Name_Of_TouchScreen!!"
        Option  "MinX"  "1267029"
        Option  "MaxX"  "16165546"
        Option  "MinY"  "615310"
        Option  "MaxY"  "14567195"
        Option  "SwapXY"        "0" # unless it was already set to 1
        Option  "InvertX"       "0"  # unless it was already set
        Option  "InvertY"       "0"  # unless it was already set
EndSection

Change '!!Name_Of_TouchScreen!!' to your device's name in the config above.
```

The calibration doesn't get applied, and putting the snippet in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf` alongside the other xorg files and rebooting has no effect. I suspect the error message about `Name 'Fujitsu Component USB Touch Panel Pen (0)' does not match any in '/sys/class/input/event*/device/name'` is the key, but there's not much information to find via Google.

Comparing the device names from the two pertinent sources:

```
chris@helmhorn:~$ cat /sys/class/input/event*/device/name | grep Fujitsu
Fujitsu Component USB Touch Panel
chris@helmhorn:~$ sudo xinput_calibrator --list
Device "Fujitsu Component USB Touch Panel Pen (0)" id=13
```

The device names don't match exactly, and putting either of those values in the xorg.conf.d file has no effect.

Edit: the best information I could find on Google was [this site in Korean](https://moebuntu.wiki.fc2.com/wiki/XP-Pen%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9%E3%83%9A%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%96%E3%81%AELinux%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6) which I had to read with a translator; basically it recommends using a different matcher like `MatchUSBID "28bd: 000c"`.

This is the clearest information I've found so far:

```
chris@helmhorn:~$ sudo xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Fujitsu Component USB Touch Panel Pen (0) id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Fujitsu Component USB Touch Panel         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Panasonic Laptop Support                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
chris@helmhorn:~$ sudo xinput_calibrator --list
Device "Fujitsu Component USB Touch Panel Pen (0)" id=13
```

It still doesn't tell me yet what's wrong, but it shows the touch panel and the pen as separate devices, and calibrator is trying to work with the pen.

Edit: I found a [recent blog post](https://cubiclenate.com/2018/04/22/panasonic-cf-19-toughbook-touch-panel-calibration/) from someone with a very similar problem on the same hardware. After xorg.conf didn't work, they decided to create a script invoking `xinput set-prop` at login time. I'll see if their solution works for me. As a bonus, they talked about on-screen keyboards, which I'll also need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I revisited this and found [this Ubuntu Forums post](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2392656.html), which correctly recommended:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

After a reboot, `xinput_calibrator` is able to identify the touchscreen and correctly calibrate it!

---

Original answer:

[This blog post](https://cubiclenate.com/2018/04/22/panasonic-cf-19-toughbook-touch-panel-calibration/) was the best workaround I could find. Rather than put the configuration in xorg.conf files, this solution invokes `xinput set-prop` in a script, which is then called at login time. This bypasses the need to figure out a nice way to tell xorg.conf which device we're talking about. It's not pretty, but it works.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Coordinate touch panel to screen

xinput set-prop "Fujitsu Component USB Touch Panel" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1.115 0 -0.073 0 1.14 -0.04 0 0 1
```

As discussed in the blog post, the best way to tune the matrix parameters seems to be trial and error. The values from the blog post were a reasonably close starting point for me.

I'd still love to hear a solution that instead uses xorg.conf and makes xinput_calibrator happy, as that would make it much easier to tune.