# Touchscreen calibration fails on Ubuntu 20.04 / PixelBook

Tags: 20.04, xorg, touchscreen, wacom, xinput

I cannot successfully calibrate the geometry of my touchscreen, running Ubuntu 20.04 on a PixelBook.  The touchscreen with stylus works OK (especially near the center of the screen) but gets progressively worse toward the display corners -- just how well-calibrated it is depends on my display resolution.  It's bad enough that it's currently quite poorly-adapted for e.g. handwriting mark-up of documents (my main use case).

The result I get from `xinput_calibrator` (after touching the four crosshairs with the stylus tip) is

```
Warning: multiple calibratable devices found, calibrating last one (WCOM50C1:00 2D1F:5143 Pen (0))
    use --device to select another one.
Calibrating standard Xorg driver "WCOM50C1:00 2D1F:5143 Pen (0)"
    current calibration values: min_x=0, max_x=16777215 and min_y=0, max_y=16777215
    If these values are estimated wrong, either supply it manually with the --precalib option, or run the 'get_precalib.sh' script to automatically get it (through HAL).
    --> Making the calibration permanent <--
  copy the snippet below into '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf' (/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ in some distro's)
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "calibration"
    MatchProduct    "!!Name_Of_TouchScreen!!"
    Option  "MinX"  "-10194"
    Option  "MaxX"  "16778670"
    Option  "MinY"  "530113"
    Option  "MaxY"  "16310016"
    Option  "SwapXY"    "0" # unless it was already set to 1
    Option  "InvertX"   "0"  # unless it was already set
    Option  "InvertY"   "0"  # unless it was already set
EndSection

Change '!!Name_Of_TouchScreen!!' to your device's name in the config above.
```

I put the suggested code snippet into the new (previously non-existent) file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf, using `Wacom|WACOM|PTK-540WL|ISD-V4` for the device name (perhaps this should be something else?).  Anyway, restarting left my touchscreen calibration just as poor as before.

The output of`xinput_calibrator --list` is

```
Device "WCOM50C1:00 2D1F:5143" id=9
Device "WCOM50C1:00 2D1F:5143 UNKNOWN" id=11
Device "WCOM50C1:00 2D1F:5143 Mouse" id=12
Device "WCOM50C1:00 2D1F:5143 Pen (0)" id=16
```

and for what it's worth, the output of `xinput --list` is

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ WCOM50C1:00 2D1F:5143                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ WCOM50C1:00 2D1F:5143 UNKNOWN             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ WCOM50C1:00 2D1F:5143 Mouse               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ACPI0C50:00 18D1:5028                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ WCOM50C1:00 2D1F:5143 Pen (0)             id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ WebCamera: WebCamera                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ WCOM50C1:00 2D1F:5143                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver               id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Any advice on how to get this touchscreen calibrated would be welcome. Many thanks!

Comment: this is how I invert the screen and calibrate the pen  setting a shortcut key to the script as  bash /home/wherever/RotateInverted sh
--output eDP and xinput map-to-output 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)'  are for you to discover. I am not sure if the 14 edp matters.
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output eDP --rotate inverted &&  xinput set-prop 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1 && xinput map-to-output 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' eDP && xinput map-to-output 14 eDP

Comment: and for normal rotation
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output eDP --rotate normal &&  xinput set-prop 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 && xinput map-to-output 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' eDP && xinput map-to-output 14 eDP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented two changes, either or both of which did the trick.

First, I followed the advice in the solution to [Trouble with xinput_calibrator on a Toughbook CF-19](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188624/) and did

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

Second, I tried `xinput_calibrator --device X` for each of the device ID numbers 'X' listed in my original question, above, until the calibration seemed better.  I finally found a value that worked, and by that point (perhaps because of the evdev/libindput changes above?) the identification of the device seemed more secure, and the text recommended for 99-calibration.conf was different.  I replaced my initial contents of that file with the lines below, and now the touchscreen seems well-calibrated:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "calibration"
    MatchProduct    "WCOM50C1:00 2D1F:5143"
    Option  "Calibration"   "41 25961 496 16806"
    Option  "SwapAxes"  "0"
EndSection
```